# EXTJS - How to send text data to server with POST

Tags: extjs

I have a URL and some DATA to POST

I try this code:

```
var par = "#DREDOCREF docrefXXX \n";
                            par += "#DREFIELDNAME XML/DOCUMENT/DREFIELD/ENTITIES/persona \n";
                            par += "#DREXMLFIELDVALUE <entitaid>2</entitaid><nominativo>Pamela Verdicchio</nominativo><nome>Pamela</nome><cognome>Verdicchio</cognome><sesso>F</sesso> \n";
                            par += "#DREFIELDNAME XML/DOCUMENT/DREFIELD/ENTITIES/persona \n";
                            par += "#DREXMLFIELDVALUE <entitaid>1</entitaid><nominativo>Mauro Rossini</nominativo><nome>Mauro</nome><cognome>Rossini</cognome><sesso>M</sesso> \n";
                            par += "#DREFIELDNAME XML/DOCUMENT/DREFIELD/ENTITIES/persona \n";
                            par += "#DREXMLFIELDVALUE <entitaid>2</entitaid><nominativo>Gino Paoli</nominativo><nome>Gino</nome><cognome>Paoli</cognome><sesso>M</sesso> \n";
                            par += "#DREFIELDNAME XML/DOCUMENT/DREFIELD/ENTITIES/persona \n";
                            par += "#DREXMLFIELDVALUE <entitaid>2</entitaid><nominativo>Anna Tatangelo</nominativo><nome>Anna</nome><cognome>XXX</cognome><sesso>F</sesso> \n";
                            par += "#DREFIELDNAME XML/DOCUMENT/DREFIELD/ENTITIES/persona \n";
                            par += "#DREXMLFIELDVALUE <entitaid>2</entitaid><nominativo>Bersani</nominativo><cognome>Bersani</cognome><sesso>M</sesso> \n";
                            par += "#DREENDDATANOOP";

Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://localhost:10111/DREREPLACE?ReplaceAllRefs=true&InsertValue=false&MultipleValues=true',
method: 'POST',
params: par,
success: function (response){
Ext.Msg.alert('POST OK');
},
failure: function (){
Ext.Msg.alert('Error Post!!');
}
});
```

the Url is sent, but DATA not. How to do?
Please help

*I can do this for example with Send Http Tools using "Text input":

Comment: what error you are getting in console.

Answer (score 1):

Use `params`, not `extraParams`. The `request` method doesn't accept an `extraParams` option.

Edit:

If you want to specify params for the URL, and data for the request body, you can use `jsonData` for the later (your `par` variable), and `params` for the URL ones.

Since your data is a string, Ext won't encode it, so you'll get the raw string in the request body. **However**, it will set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, which means a proper server will decode the string to objects... So to be clean, you should set an appropriate content-type yourself.

To sum it up:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    // URL params
    params: {
        ReplaceAllRefs: true,
        ...
    }

    // data
    jsonData: par,

    // fixed header
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},

    ...
});
```

Comment: I used, but i can't send DATA too

Comment: Do you mean you want to configure both URL params, and body data? See my update.

Comment: First of all thnak you so much :-D Yes i must send that Url (with that param) and i must send data as assigned in var "par" too. The send start, but remain in wait mode end after few seconds Abort.

Comment: I must do in Ext same that i can do with classic tool that send something to Http. One is "Http Send tool" do you know? In that program i specify a Url: xxx and a Text: xxx and works

Comment: I think I misunderstood your first comment. You don't get the payload if you just replace `extraParams` with `params` or `jsonData` in your code example? I've tested this, and my server received the request body in both case >_<